# Unable to inject $resouce angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use $resouce for REST API call, but i am getting below error.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter.services due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module $resource due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module '$resource' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=%24resource
    at http://localhost:8080/stockpicker/stockPickerApp/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13438:12
    at http://localhost:8080/stockpicker/stockPickerApp/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15404:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:8080/stockpicker/stockPickerApp/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15328:38)
    at module (http://localhost:8080/stockpicker/stockPickerApp/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15402:14)
    at http://localhost:8080/stockpicker/stockPickerApp/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17894:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:8080/stockpicker/stockPickerApp/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13691:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8080/stockpicker/stockPickerApp/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17878:5)
    at http://localhost:8080/stockpicker/stockPickerApp/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17895:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:8080/stockpicker/stockPickerApp/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13691:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8080/stockpicker/stockPickerApp/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17878:5)
```

below is my index.html where i have included angular.js and angular-resouce.js

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">
...
...
```

below is the content from my app.js

```
angular.module('starter', [ 'ionic', 'ionic.service.core', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services','ngResource'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
```

Content from service.js

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['$resource']).factory('StockPickerService', function($http,$resource) {
// Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array
```

Am i missing anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject `ngResource` in module `starter.services`, not `$resource`.

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['ngResource']).factory('StockPickerService', function($http,$resource) {
// Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array
```

Answer (score 1):

`ngResource` is the module that provides the `$resource` service.

So

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['ngResource']).factory('StockPickerService', function($http,$resource) { }
```

should work